asusrouter python library for radio on 5Ghz
Colud someone help me with my problem regarding this asusrouter python library I have a code that turn on the wlan radio on my Asus AX55:
    result = await router.async_set_state(
        AsusWLAN.ON,
        arguments={
            "api_type": "wlan",
            "api_id": "0",
            "expected_arguments": {"wl0_radio": 1}
        }
    )

I'm refering to this script: https://github.com/Vaskivskyi/asusrouter
But it's only turn radio on for 2.4Ghz...How can I switch radio on also for 5Ghz ?

https://github.com/Vaskivskyi/asusrouter/blob/main/asusrouter/modules/wlan.py#L31

@Martheen thanks for pointing this but I don't know how to handle that:
like that:    result = await router.async_set_state(
AsusWLAN.ON,
arguments={
"api_type": "wlan",
"api_id": "0",
"expected_arguments": {"wl1_radio": 1}
}
)  ??? It's not working

So, it should look like that:
result = await router.async_set_state(
AsusWLAN.ON,
api_type="wlan",
api_id=1)

